# MS Access Populate TextBox and Combox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I beleive this is an easy question for you guys, but I'm really new to MS Access and VBA, so I need your help. I have two tables, Purchase and Purchase Details, with a corresponding Form for each table. What I want is when I click on the Purchase table primary key it will load another form containing all the details based on that key and populate all the textboxes and combobox.

From this form:

[image: From this form]

To this form:

[image: To this form]

Comment: You'll need to use the OpenArgs property.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836583.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use the OpenArgs property (as suggested in a comment) or simply open the form with a filter.

In the OnClick event of the key, add something like this (you'll need to change this based on your actual form/table/field names):

```
CustomerOrderForm.RecordSource = "SELECT * from PurchaseDetails WHERE OrderNumber = '" & Me.ID & "'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the form so that it displays the information that you want for all purchases, then use cmd.openform using the WhereCondition argument to filter by just the Purchase entry that you want to display.